# Complex Gestures in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've struggled with this for days and just can't come up with a solution. I've been tasked with converting our Objective-C app to SwiftUI, and we have some very complex gestures in a tableview that supports holding a cell, while being able to scroll the tableView with the same finger that's holding the cell, and also scroll the tableView with a second finger. I'm trying to find a way to do this in SwiftUI but just can't figure it out. Here's a simple example:

```
struct ListViewCell: View {
    @GestureState var isDragging = false

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .updating($isDragging) { value, state, transaction in
                state = true
            }
        Rectangle()
            .fill(isDragging ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .delaysTouches(for: 0.2, onTap: {})
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    let data = [
        "Test 1","Test 2","Test 3","Test 4","Test 5",
        "Test 6","Test 7","Test 8","Test 9","Test 10",
        "Test 11","Test 12","Test 13","Test 14","Test 15",
        "Test 16","Test 17","Test 18","Test 19","Test 20"
      ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                ListViewCell()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this lets me scroll without holding a cell, and lets me hold a cell without scrolling, but I cannot for the life of me come up with a way to allow for the holding of the cell, and still allow that same finger to scroll the list view. I've tried to pass the drag offset back to the ListView through a callback, then have the ListView scroll itself manually based on the offset, but this approach loses scroll inertia and introduces a bunch of other issues as well. This isn't hard to achieve with UIKit gestures but I'm wondering if it's even possible in SwiftUI. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Update: You'll need this view extension or else the List won't scroll, as the drag gesture would otherwise interfere:

```
extension View {
func delaysTouches(for duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, onTap action: @escaping () -> Void = {}) -> some View {
    modifier(DelaysTouches(duration: duration, action: action))
}
```

}

Comment: I doubt it can be done with List. ScrollViewReader might be an option but you will likely have to use UIKit

Comment: I couldn't get ScrollViewReader to work in the way I wanted, but using the Introspect library does give me access to the underlying tableView. The issue isn't getting the tableView to scroll, it's getting the same gesture that holds the ListViewCell to also scroll that table, and then also having a second finger drag the List